# Simple Java (about inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance

A MovingVan object should have all of the same state and behavior as a Truck object. In addition, it should maintain additional state that keeps track of:
the distance from the ground to the floor of the cargo area (a positive integer)
whether it has a ramp (true or false)
When a MovingVan object is printed, it should display its capacity, its distance to the cargo area, and whether it has a ramp. For example:

```
capacity = 10000, distance to cargo = 5, has a ramp
```

Your class definition should include the following:

1) write a constructor that takes as parameters the make, model, year, number of wheels, and distance to the cargo area, and a boolean value indicating whether the moving van has a ramp. The constructor should ensure that the object is not put in an invalid state, and it should take whatever steps are needed to initialize the object.

2) any necessary instance methods. You should assume that the distance to the cargo area and the presence or absence of a ramp will never change, and thus mutator methods are not needed for those fields.

---

This is what I have so far. For number 1, I have :

```
public MovingVan(String make, String model, int year, int numWheels, 
                   int distance, boolean hasRamp) {
      super(make, model, year, numWheels);

      if (distance <= 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      this.distance = distance;
      this.hasRamp = hasRamp;
  }
```

I have trouble with number 2; this is what I have so far:

```
public int getDistance() {
      return distance;
  }

public boolean hasRamp() {
      return hasRamp;
  }
```

Am I missing something? I feel like I am missing some other necessary instance methods?? What do you think?

Comment: what about capacity manipulations.

Comment: Is this a homework or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
More of a comment that an answer, but I needed the extra space
```

Not bad, but depending of your teacher POV you may be missing

1) a `getCapacity()` metod (you have to print it).

2) or an implementation of `toString()` where the data is formed as an human readable string.

In any case, it would be good to have a "getter" `getX()` method for each attribute passed in the constructor.

In a minor note, a getter method that returns a boolean usually begins with `is` (in fact it MUST if you want to call your class a bean). `isRamp()` sounds strange anyway, maybe `isRampIncorporated()`?

Additionally, since `distance` is a value that in the real world may change often, I would add a `setDistance` method.

Answer (score 0):

When a MovingVan object is printed, it should display its capacity, its distance to the cargo area, and whether it has a ramp. Example: capacity = 10000, distance to cargo = 5, has a ramp

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return "capacity = " + capacity /*or getCapacity()? I can't tell*/ + ", distance to cargo = " + distance + (hasRamp)?", has a ramp":", does not have a ramp";
}
```

Not sure about anything else but it sounds like (s)he wants you to override toString()

Also make sure you have gets/sets where applicable.